# Report Viewer with custom Column and Fields

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report

So first this is my schema my master

[image]

so details contain 3 foreignkey from color model and size

for example this is my data in item details

[image]

so i wanna create my report rdlc like this
[image]

so my question is how to create report like that and how to add column according much data `Size` i have in that report if after query item details that item and model only have 3 size so only show 3 column size and if i only have 2 size only have 2 column at upper report . same condition with color
if have size for example medium but color is null so in report show empty or "-"

note : for date is empty space for manual reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new report and add your dataset.

Add a Matrix control to your report. The new matrix control will have cells marked  for 'Rows', 'Columns' and 'Data' like below

[image]

Drag the `COLOR_NAME` field from the dataset onto the 'Rows' cell, drag `SIZE` onto 'columns' and `QTY` onto data.

If you run your report now you will get a basic version of what you want.
[image]

To add the extra row you need, right-click the SIZE Column and do 'Insert Row' -> Inside Group - Below

Next, right click the cell that was just a created and do 'Insert Column' -> 'Inside Group - Right'. 
Type you r headers ('qty' and `date`) in the respective columns

Finally, the size column groups are sorted alphabetically so we need to change them, luckily we can just reverse the order with real data I suggest you supply a sorting field in your dataset so you can sort the columns how you wish.

To reverse the sort order, Click the drop down next to the `SIZE` column group in the area just below the report design and choose 'Group Properties'. Click 'Sorting' and then change the Order to `Z-A`

Now the final report design looks like this.

[image]

A few tiny formatting updates to center things and the final output looks like this.

[image]